# PyQt4 segmentation fault when assigning text to QGraphicsSimpleTextItem

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pyqt, qgraphicstextitem

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on Ubuntu 13.10 and the PyQt4 version is 4.10.2. I'm new to PyQt and the following code demonstrates how I get the segmentation fault.
after starting the python interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> obj=QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
>>> obj.setText('sometext')
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

or initialize directly with string:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> obj2=QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem('some text')
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

or set text with QString object:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
>>> s=QtCore.QString('sometext')
>>> obj=QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
>>> obj.setText(s)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I must have missed something very basic. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always create an QApplication instance before trying to use GUI objects/widgets:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 26 2013, 12:52:49) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> obj = QtGui.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem()
>>> obj.setText('foo')
>>>
```

Its a good idea to add a function to your `.pythonrc.py` which does all the necessary imports and setup for a pyqt interactive session - saves a lot of tedious re-typing!

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro. I just tried your code and it worked. Do you mind pointing me to some references or keywords so I can further understand how qt works? Because this seems couter-intuitive to me...

Comment: @user3126725. The primary reference is the [Qt Documentation](https://qt-project.org/doc/). For details on QApplication, [see here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#details). For PyQt-specific stuff, just do a websearch for `pyqt tutorial` - there's tons of stuff out there. And you can always come back to SO if you have specific programming problems. Good luck!